# How to create a display

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I am trying to create a msg display for a friend in Minecraft. The display works with 2x2 "pixel". However, I cannot come up with a way to make the 2x2 pixel light up, in a repeatable, stackable pattern.

On the left-hand side is what I need to be able to do, and on the right-hand side is an example of what needs to be done, just without the border between the "pixels".
[image: What I need versus what I don't need]

Essentially what I need to do is be able to toggle between this message and two other ones. Meaning, i need to be able to turn off the pixels and on etc.
[image: What the end result needs to do]

Answer (score 1):

Using Redstone Torches I have come up with a modular design to lighting up the Redstone Lamps. Do note the default state is on and you may need to invert the signal.

Modular:
[image]

The redstone dust on the right needs to be interchanged with  blocks when tiling.

Front View:
[image]

Side View:
[image]

Back View:
[image]

As you can see the redstone dust is raised up at each interval so they will not conflict with other lines.